# How to make a hyperlink text bold in overleaf resume?

Tags: overleaf

I was trying to add a link to my project but on adding a hyperlink I am unable to make it bold can anyone help please..

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47468/how-to-make-url-bold) if you want to use `\url`.

If you use `\href` from the `hyperref` package you could simply wrap the text in `\textbf`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Removes boxes around link and makes them blue
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
%%

\begin{document}

This is an example of a \textbf{\href{https://stackoverflow.com}{bold link}}.

Where this is \href{https://stackoverflow.com}{not a bold link}.


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]